# How to convert a base64 source to image source in xamarin

Tags: c#, image, xamarin

I want to convert a svg base64 string to image and need to assign that to image source in Xamarin How to implement the same . Please help on this.

```
Var dImage="data:image/avg+XML;base64,PD94b.....=="
```

My base64 string is in the above format.I did the normal base64 to image convertion but it didn't worked.

Comment: please post the relevant code you tried to use

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try it with plain data (without mime-type,...):

=> `Convert.FromBase64String("PD94b.....==");`

```cs
var dImage = "data:image/avg+XML;base64,PD94b.....==";

var base64 = dImage.Split(',')[1];
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

Image image;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```